# How to locate the changes in file of the last modification?

Tags: filesystems, vim

I was using `vim` to modify a `lua` file, after modifying it and saving the file,  I get some problem on the project.

I want to find the last modification of the file before I saved it, what can I do?

Comment: if your version of `vim` is still configured to keep backup copies upon saving, you should have a backup of `file` at `file~` in the same directory.

Comment: @DopeGhoti no, there isn't

Comment: Whoops. This is why it is a good practice to use a version control system. git is good.

Answer (score 3):

If `vim` is configured to save backups (with `:set backup`), a backup will have been saved with a `~` suffix.

If this option is not turned on, and if you did not manually back up the file before editing it (or store it in a version control system), then the original file (before editing) is unfortunately lost.

With the `backup` option set, a backup will be stored in the same directory as the original file (unless changed by setting `backupdir`) with a `~` suffix (unless changed by setting `backupext` to another string).